# What is behind the statement "Were it not 'Iyad the Maghrib would be unknown"?

Tags: history, source-identification, islamic-scholar

There's a famous quote about [al-Qadi 'Iyad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qadi_Ayyad) القاضي عياض بن موسى, which is often mentioned:

> لولا عياض لما عُرف المغرب/
> لولا عياض ما عرف المغرب

Which translates to:

> Where it not 'Iyad the Maghrib would be unknown

Or an other version of the quote saying:

> لولا عياض ما ذُكر المغرب

Which translates to:

> Where it not 'Iyad the Maghrib wouldn't be mentioned

This quote(s) may refer to the depth of 'Iyad's knowledge, these are his well renowned works:

- [a-Shifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash-Shifa)  [الشفا](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%81%D8%A7_%D8%A8%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%81_%D8%AD%D9%82%D9%88%D9%82_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B7%D9%81%D9%89) بتعريف حقوق المصطفى about attributes and miracles of the Prophet (pbuh)
- Mashqriq al-Anwar  مشارق الأنوار على صحاح الآثار about difficult terms and strangeness (gharib) or errors in the narrations of sahih al-Bukhari, sahih Muslim and al-Muwatta'
- Ikmal al-Mu'allim [إكمال المعلم](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%83%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85_%D8%A8%D9%81%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF_%D8%B5%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%AD_%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85) بفوائد صحيح مسلم a commentary on sahih Muslim
- [al-I'laam](http://www.muwatta.com/ebooks/english/qadi_iyad_foundations.pdf) bi hudood qawa'id al-Islam [الإعلام بحدود قواعد الإسلام](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85_%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AF_%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85_(%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8)) about the foundations of Islam: a-Shahadatan, as-Salat, as-Siyam, a-Zakat and al-Hajj
- tarteeb al-Madarik -his book on the Maliki madhhab and its scholars- [ترتيب المدارك](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%83_%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83_%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%A9_%D8%A3%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85_%D9%85%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8_%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83) وتقريب المسالك لمعرفة أعلام مذهب مالك

However this could also refer to the fact that 'Iyad was among the first scholars from the western Islamic states that didn't need to travel to the east (al-Mashriq) to seek knowledge, as the west (al-Maghrib) and Muslim Iberian peninsula (al-Andalus) had enough great scholars.

My question are:

- Does this famous quote have a source?
- Are there further explanations and meanings of this quote? And if so which?

Comment: When I translate the whole quote it replaces al-Maghrib (west) to Morocco.

Comment: @AbduRahman المغرب may refer to the place of sunset (which is also in الغرب al-Gharb the west), to the counties of the great Maghreb meaning Morocco, Algeria,Tunisia,Lybia and Mauretania -historically- and the country known as Morocco. it might also be used to refer to الغرب الإسلامي the west side of Muslim countries which is normally referring to the historical Maghreb and sl- Andalus vs. المشرق which often refers to middle east.

Answer (score 0):

The quote "Were it not 'Iyad the Maghrib would be unknown" is attributed to various sources, but it is commonly believed to have originated from Ibn Tumart, the founder of the Almohad movement, who praised 'Iyad's intellectual and religious contributions. According to some sources, the quote was mentioned in a eulogy by Ibn Tumart at 'Iyad's funeral, while others contend that it was said in a conversation with 'Iyad.

In any case, the quote has become a well-known testament to 'Iyad's role in advancing Islamic scholarship in the Maghreb and beyond. Through his many works, including those mentioned in the previous answer, 'Iyad made significant contributions to the fields of hadith, fiqh, theology, and biographical literature. His writings were highly regarded by his contemporaries and subsequent generations of scholars, and continue to be studied and referenced today.

Beyond his intellectual achievements, 'Iyad was also known for his moral and ethical character. He was revered for his humility, piety, and commitment to serving his community. This combination of intellectual and ethical excellence contributed to his lasting legacy as one of the great scholars of the Islamic tradition.

**In summary, the quote "Were it not 'Iyad the Maghrib would be unknown" reflects the profound impact that 'Iyad had on Islamic scholarship in the Maghreb and beyond.** It highlights both his intellectual achievements and his moral character, and has become a lasting tribute to his legacy.

Comment: First of all ibn Tumart died about 20 years before 'Iyad, who beside being a scholar and a Maliki and non-Asha'ari was among the leaders of the defenders of Sebta (also known as Ceuta) the last city the al-Morabits lost against the al-Mowahhideen. Secondly 'Iyad was brought to Marrakesh after Sebta has fallen and killed by al-Mowahideen. These are some reasons to doubt this claim. Actually 'Iyad moved back to Sebta around 5 years before his death. Both scholars however could have met since 'Iyad was two years younger than ibn Tumart and both have been in al-Andalus at the same time.