# Is Qadi Iyad's Kitab Ash Shifa reliable?

Tags: authenticity, books

Assalamoalikum, I wanted to learn if Qadi Iyad's Kitab Ash Shifa is a reliable source among Sunni scholars or not. I am asking this in the sense of the author's reliability and writings. Of course, some Sahih and Da'if Hadith references are found inside the book. Still, this question has a lesser focus on the Hadith references but rather on the reliability of the content in the book written by Qadi Iyad himself.

Comment: See for example [What is behind the statement were it not 'Iyad the maghrib would be unknown](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45465/what-is-behind-the-statement-where-it-not-iyad-the-maghrib-would-be-unknown)

Comment: This book is well known and accepted adn many scholars have even written commentaries on it (see in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Al-Shifa_bi_Ta%27rif_Huquq_al-Mustafa&oldid=1089503251).

Comment: @Medi1Saif I'll take a look, Jazak Allah khair.

Comment: @Jamila Jazak Allah, I have bookmarked both of the links you two have sent, if it would be possible to write a brief answer according to the content, then that would be great for future readers as well insha Allah.

Comment: Qadi Iyyad is a famous classical authority in the Maaliki Madhab